# Warnings on creating private setters in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have two properties declared for my class in its interface file Account.h

```
@interface Account : NSObject {
    NSString* username;
    NSString* password;
}

@property (readonly) NSString* username;
@property (readonly) NSString* password;

@end
```

And I have created private setters in its implementation file Account.m

```
@interface Account()

@property (copy, readwrite) NSString* username;
@property (copy, readwrite) NSString* password;

@end
```

But, I get warnings from XCode (v3.x) on the above two lines in the implementation file. And this is the warning.

```
warning: property 'username' attribute in 'Account' class continuation does not match class 'Account' property
```

Why is this warning given by XCode. These warnings are all over my project. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include the `copy` specifier in the .h file as well:

```
@property (copy, readonly) NSString* username;
@property (copy, readonly) NSString* password;
```

Comment: but according to the interface file, the setters doesn't exists. Right? So, its kinda weird to put 'copy' there.

Comment: Yes, it looks weird. But if you omit `copy`, the default is `assign`, and you can't override an existing `assign` declaration later with `copy` or `retain`.

Comment: thanks. it worked. but i don't get why objectiveC should give a default writing strategy (assign) when i ask it just for the reader.